# Ubuntu-Gnome 15.04: USB 3.0 HDD very slow

Tags: gnome, usb, nautilus, usb-drive

Following situation: If I connect my USB 3.0 HDD (WD MyPassport) to the USB 3.0 Interface of my laptop and then try to copy a large file with nautilus the speed only reaches around 10MB/sec.

So I read that you got to have the module *xhci_hcd* loaded. But if I put this in the /etc/modules file and reboot, nautilus won't automount the drive anymore.

No, the file system of the external disk drive is not NTFS or FAT, it's EXT4. Here is the output from *mount -l*:

```
> /dev/sdb2 on /media/user/BACKUP type ext4
> (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks2) [BACKUP]
```

So why isn't this USB 3.0 module loaded by default? And why does it break nautilus? Is this a bug or a configuration issue?

Any help is much apreciated.

Comment: Did you try using rsync? See if you get the same speed there too.

Comment: How you tried to `modporbe xhci_hcd`?

Comment: I think when I last tried USB 3 on Ubuntu it should be fine (and quicker for larger files) - are you using a USB 3 port and cable, and what is are the drive's partition() formatted as?

Comment: @Raphael: No, didn't try that yet. Good idea though. Thx!

Comment: @Yurii Kolesnykov: I put the line `xhci_hcd` in the file _/etc/modules_

Comment: @Wilf: Yeah cable and port are all USB 3. And as I said the file system is EXT4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded now to the new **Ubuntu 15.10** and **Gnome-Shell 3.18**. Then I tested again with Nautilus and USB 3. Now the speed is fine: over 100MB/sec.